# Returning multiple arrays from function in .NET webservice

Tags: .net, arrays, web-services

I need to define a method which returns multiple arrays in .NET. i have tried using "Tuple" but it needs the method to be declared "private". in my case, i am using web service and when i declare method private, it does not appear in list of methods of webservice. can somebody suggest me what to do?

Comment: why does it need to be private if you want to *expose* it in a web service. you can't have both.

Comment: Is this an `ASMX Web Service`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an `IEnumerable<int[]>` for example. Just make sure that you use the correct type instead of `int`.

BTW: Using `Tuple` doesn't imply that you have to make your method private. There is something else going on with this.

Comment: if i use this, what should be written with retun statement. i mean return statement will be like : return ......??

Comment: @justalearner: I have no idea how you get your arrays. But it would probably look something like this: `return new List<int[]> { array1, array2, array3 };`